# jQuery get all node names (both parent and children)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have an XML document that gets generated by an object.  I have no idea what it will really look like at the time of the jQuery AJAX call.  What I would like to do is parse through the XML by parent and child getting the node names.

Any direction you can offer will be of great service.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have control over this webservice? If you do, would you consider returning a JSON object instead of XML? JSON is much easier and faster to work with.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have control...  It is XML and will stay XML at least until the next version...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to parse through XML the same way you parse through DOM elements in jquery;

http://jsfiddle.net/TBwm8/3/

```
var xml = "<root><stuff></stuff><stuff><stuffchild></stuffchild></stuff></root>";

function alertit(jqueryObject) {
    if (jqueryObject.length === 0) return;

    jqueryObject.each(function() {
        alert(this.nodeName.toLowerCase());
    });

    alertit(jqueryObject.children());
}

alertit($(xml));
```

Comment: Well that looks easy enough...  Thanks!  This looks to be the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [jParse](http://jparse.kylerush.net/)?

Comment: It looks like I need to know the elements and that is what I need to find out.  Does jQuery not have a way to parse and XML doc?